# Angular2, Browser back button displays blank screen

Tags: angular2-routing

I am new to Angular2. In my app, please find below routing configuration.

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginHomepageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginHomepageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'default',
    component: DefaultNavigationBarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'mainContent',
    component: MainContentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'changepassword', component: ChangePasswordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'searchResults', component: SearchResultsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'addUser', component: AddUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canDeactivate: [UnsavedChangesGuard] }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
    data: {
      message: 'Page not found!'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'declarationofuse',
    component: DeclarationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/not-found'
  }
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true });
```

in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRouting,
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    UnsavedChangesGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
export function cookieServiceFactory() { return new CookieService(); }
```

When I logged in into application, it works perfectly and each and every page is getting loaded successfully.

***Issue occurres while user follow below steps***

- Login to Application, automatically loads /declarationofuse uri
- Now user goes to google.com, and after that user press the back button

Browser shows **blank page only**, however uri in url bar shows /declarationofuse url. There are no exception thrown in console tab as well.

Comment: add LoginComponent

Comment: @srikanth_k: LoginHomepageComponent is the LoginComponent